# Bind date without time conversion issue between DateTime and DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an API and the API take input in body as below,

```
{"CreatedDate" :"2022-11-01", "CreatedDate1" :"2022-11-01"}
```

The API have a Dto which have 2 properties to bind these values,

```
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate1 { get; set; }
```

One is DateTime and another DateTimeOffet. When I run the API I see the below results,

```
dto.CreatedDate.ToString()
"11/1/2022 12:00:00 AM"
dto.CreatedDate.ToLocalTime().ToString()
"11/1/2022 4:00:00 AM"
dto.CreatedDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString()
"10/31/2022 8:00:00 PM"
dto.CreatedDate1.ToString()
"11/1/2022 12:00:00 AM +04:00"
dto.CreatedDate1.ToLocalTime().ToString()
"11/1/2022 12:00:00 AM +04:00"
dto.CreatedDate1.ToUniversalTime().ToString()
"10/31/2022 8:00:00 PM +00:00"
```

I am confused by `CreatedDate1.ToString()` and `CreatedDate1.ToLocalTime().ToString()` are same but `CreatedDate.ToString()` and `CreatedDate.ToLocalTime().ToString()` are not.

Does this intended behavior of `DateTime`?

Comment: It depends on how `DateTime.Kind` is set. The default, `Unspecified`, will result in adjustment. `DateTimeOffset` has no kind since it doesn't need one (the point in time is unambiguous). `DateTime.SpecifyKind` can be used to override this when necessary.

Comment: Yeah the kind is `Unspecified`. What adjustment do you mean. My code is running under +4 and the difference between UTC and Local is +8 (see above)

Comment: I mean that the `DateTime` is assumed to be `Utc` if you call `.ToLocalTime()` on an `Unspecified` `DateTime` (which makes some sense, since otherwise, why would you be adjusting it). If you know the `DateTime` is supposed to be local, use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` after deserializing to indicate that, then `.ToLocalTime()` will not change the input (alternatively, find some property or setting in the deserializer that will set the `DateTime` to a specific `Kind`; for example, Newtonsoft.Json has `DateTimeZoneHandling`).